# Finding an algorithm that can find the shortest way to solve a one dimensional variant of the "lights out" game

Tags: algorithm

I'm solving a task from an old programming competition. The task is to make a program that can find if there exists a possible solution, and what the shortest solution is, for a version of the well known game "lights out". In short, we have several lights connected. By clicking on of the lights you change the status of it, and the two adjacent lights. The goal is to activate all the lights.

In the classic version of "lights out" we are working with two dimensions, but in this version the lights are connected in a "one dimensional" string, where the "edges" are connected. Basically a circle of lights.
The number of lights can go up to 10000, so the bruteforce method I tried was obviously not good enough. It only manages to solve the versions that have a solution, and where there are under ~10 lights. Here is an example of a solveable setup. The 1's mark lights that are activated, and the 0's mark lights that are deactivated. The first line includes the number of lights in the string. If a solution doesn't excist, the program will output that it isn't possible. Remember that the edges are connected.

5
10101

Click one of the "edges" (doesn't matter which one, I clicked the left one).

01100

Click the opposite edge

11111

If a solution doesn't excist the program outputs a message. If not, it outputs the shortest solution, in this case: 2.

Could anyone help me find an algorithm?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Stack overflow is a *question* and answer site, but I don't see a single question mark in this post. Strange.

Comment: try a BFS-search over all possible states of the lights, where states that can be transformed into each other are connected by an edge.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I would presume that most people here could see from the title that it is implied that I am looking for an algorithm? Especially since I mentioned in the post that I had even tried other methods. It also seems like Paul here was able to understand my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you knew whether in the solution (if one exists) you need to click on the first and second light.

Once we have this information, we can immediately deduce whether we need to click on the third light as this is the last choice that can affect the second light (clicking on the first light changes the last/first/second, clicking on the second light changes the first/second/third, clicking on the third light changes the second/third/fourth - but no other clicks can change the second light).

Similarly, we can then immediately deduce whether to click the fourth light, as this is the last choice that can affect the third light.

You can then work all the way round to the end to find out whether you have a consistent solution (with all lights out).

Simply try all 4 options for the first 2 switches, and pick the best scoring one.

Complexity O(4n)

Comment: Hey, could I just ask for some clarification on the first sentence? "Suppose you knew whether you clicked on the first and second light." What do you mean by that? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Because clicking on the lights twice cancels the effect, the solution to any lights out puzzle is specified by saying exactly which of the lights are clicked on.  My point is that you can simply try all 4 choices for whether the first 2 lights are clicked on (once these are chosen, all the rest are easily determined)

Comment: Okay, again, thanks for the help. I'll try to set up a solution using this.